# Using a variable declared outside the Query string inside a SPARQL Query- Using JSP and Java Servlet

Tags: java, nlp, sparql, rdf, jena

I have 2 jsp pages. In the index page I am selecting a dropdown value and passing the selected value as a url parameter to the SearchResults page.

```
http://localhost:8080/SearchResults.jsp?jobCat=InformationTechnology
```

I am capturing the parameter `InformationTechnology` passed using below code . The query should show results for the selected value in the form. (I am selecting a job category and the results should show the candidates under selected job category)

```
String jobCategory = request.getParameter("jobCat");
```

Below is my Query

```
String queryString =
"Select ?a ?b"+
" Where { ...."+
" Filter (?a = "+ jobCategory  +")"+// jobCategory is the String variable 
" }";
```

But I am getting ParseException Error.

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "in" "In "" at line 
1, column 559.
Was expecting one of:
<IRIref> ...
<PNAME_NS> ...
<PNAME_LN> ...
<VAR1> ...
<VAR2> ...
"exists" ...
"not" ...
"count" ...
"min" ...
"max" ...
"sum" ...
"avg" ...
"sample" ...
"group_concat" ...
"bound" ...
"coalesce" ...
"if" ...
"bnode" ...
"iri" ...
"uri" ...
"str" ...
"strlang" ...
"strdt" ...
"datatype" ...
"lang" ...
"langmatches" ...
"isURI" ...
"isIRI" ...
"isBlank" ...
"isLiteral" ...
"isNumeric" ...
"regex" ...
"sameTerm" ...
"RAND" ...
"ABS" ...
"CEIL" ...
"FLOOR" ...
"ROUND" ...
"CONCAT" ...
"SUBSTR" ...
"STRLEN" ...
"UCASE" ...
"LCASE" ...
"ENCODE_FOR_URI" ...
"CONTAINS" ...
"strSTARTS" ...
"strENDS" ...
"YEAR" ...
"MONTH" ...
"DAY" ...
"HOURS" ...
"MINUTES" ...
"SECONDS" ...
"TIMEZONE" ...
"TZ" ...
"NOW" ...
"MD5" ...
"SHA1" ...
"SHA224" ...
"SHA256" ...
"SHA384" ...
"SHA512" ...
"true" ...
"false" ...
<INTEGER> ...
<DECIMAL> ...
<DOUBLE> ...
<INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
<DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
<DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
<INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
<DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
<DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
<STRING_LITERAL1> ...
<STRING_LITERAL2> ...
<STRING_LITERAL_LONG1> ...
<STRING_LITERAL_LONG2> ...
"(" ...
"!" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
```

Is there an alternative way to use the string variable inside a SPARQL query like in similar scenario. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/parameterized-sparql-strings.html

Comment: always, please print the final query string before it's getting parsed and look at it - it's obvious that you have to wrap the URI between `<` and `>`

Comment: Just an remark: package `com.hp.hpl.jena` means that it is old Jena (Jena2). It does not support SPARQL 1.1 fully

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ssz . I have updated the package to org.apache.jena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this issue.
I used `regex` to obtain the result

```
"filter(regex(?a, \"" + jobCategory + "\"))"
```

Comment: If the string matches exactly the literal you are searching it is better to treat the literal als object instead of extra filter because Regex is slow

Answer (score 1):

I assume jobCategory is a Literal/Label? Simple ask directly for the label.

```
String queryString =
"Select ?a ?b"+
" Where { <uri> <uri>\""  + jobCategory +"\"}";
```

I case it is a URI the query would look like.

```
String queryString =
"Select ?a ?b"+
" Where { <uri> <uri> <" + jobCategory+ ">}";
```